# What could be the best workout routine for loosing fat and building muscle simultaneously including weight training and cardio?

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines

I would start with the short phrase "Transformation goal:Tyler Durden".
I am 31 yrs, 6 feet and 91 kgs with sitting job.My routine is as follows:

-Monday : Back + Cardio(HIIT)
   -Tuesday :Chest + Cardio(HIIT)
   -Wednesday :Biceps +Triceps + Abs+ Cardio(HIIT)
   -Thursday :Shoulders + Abs + Cardio(HIIT)
   -Friday :Legs+ Abs + Cardio(HIIT)
   -Saturday :Full body compound exercises+ Cardio(HIIT)

I warm up for 5 minutes with running or rope jumping then stretch for next 5 minutes and then start with the weights. 10-12 reps for 3 sets, i try to do atleast 3 exercise per body part.
Diet is almost fine and complete with protein, fat and carbs as major constituents.
I need that missing additional factor that could help me reaching my goal, or at least nearly reaching it.

Comment: The additional factor would be **persistence**! ;) It could be 2 months, it could be 6. Keep it up and it will happen. (But might be good to change some of those cardio(HIIT) days to regular jogging)

Answer (score 1):

Most people have different phases - for building muscles, and loosing weight. You simply can't lost only fat, and do that fast. When loosing weight, you go down with calories, and muscles also go away. That is why people build more muscles, and then go to "definition".

Watching your plan - I would think about walking. Treadmill, constant heart rate - for fat burning, one hour. You can listen to podcasts, read something - what ever - just walk.

As @Y12K suggested. Think about longer plan. You are going to the target in steps. At the gym steps are measured in two weeks. From that blocks you can build phases - like muscle building, or loosing weight. Then next phase. Other option is to target more different muscles. For instance, target your squats, do max. Then go down, just to maintain proper level, and go to dead lift, or bench press. You wouldn't get bored. Something is changing, but two weeks blocks allow stability, control.